# Recursive approcah to solve Towers of Hanoi Problem

Tags: python

I just learn about Recursion and tried to solve Towers of Hanoi problem. I know the description about the Towers of Hanoi by book description (I use book Data Structures and Algorithmic Thinking with Python by Narasimha Karumanchi) and the book gives me solution to solve the problem:

```
def Tower_of_Hanoi(Number_of_disc, start_rods = 1, end_rods = 3):
    if Number_of_disc:
        Tower_of_Hanoi(Number_of_disc-1, start_rods, 6-start_rods-end_rods)
        print(f"Move disc {Number_of_disc}, from start {start_rods} to {end_rods}")
        Tower_of_Hanoi(Number_of_disc-1, 6-start_rods-end_rods, end_rods)
```

What I don't understand is the line `6-start_rods-end_rods`. How this line works? Is this operator just like *append, sort, etc.* or this is a *syntax* that have meaning behind it. This is my first question.

Then, I tried to run it, I give `Number_of_disc` by 5, and here's the result:

```
Move disc 1, from start 1 to 3
Move disc 2, from start 1 to 2
Move disc 1, from start 3 to 2
Move disc 3, from start 1 to 3
Move disc 1, from start 2 to 1
Move disc 2, from start 2 to 3
Move disc 1, from start 1 to 3
Move disc 4, from start 1 to 2
Move disc 1, from start 3 to 2
Move disc 2, from start 3 to 1
Move disc 1, from start 2 to 1
Move disc 3, from start 3 to 2
Move disc 1, from start 1 to 3
Move disc 2, from start 1 to 2
Move disc 1, from start 3 to 2
Move disc 5, from start 1 to 3
Move disc 1, from start 2 to 1
Move disc 2, from start 2 to 3
Move disc 1, from start 1 to 3
Move disc 3, from start 2 to 1
Move disc 1, from start 3 to 2
Move disc 2, from start 3 to 1
Move disc 1, from start 2 to 1
Move disc 4, from start 2 to 3
Move disc 1, from start 1 to 3
Move disc 2, from start 1 to 2
Move disc 1, from start 3 to 2
Move disc 3, from start 1 to 3
Move disc 1, from start 2 to 1
Move disc 2, from start 2 to 3
Move disc 1, from start 1 to 3
```

I know some disc will be move from one rod (or ped) to the other, but my question is how the function know when to move specific disc from source to the ped and then move again to the other ped? For example, take *disc 1*, from the result above *line 1* said that disc moved from 1 to 3, then on *line 3* said that disc move from 3 to 2. I think this move have connection with line `6-star_rods-end_rods`, but I don't know how it's works behind the line.

Please, help me.

Comment: `6-start_rods-end_rods` means `6` (the number six) minus the value of the variable `start_rods` minus the value of the variable `end_rods`. IMO spaces between the operands would improve readability (compare with `6 - start_rods - end_rods`), but it should be easy enough to recognize the syntax if you're at a level where you're learning about recursion.

Comment: It is using the mathematical identity (A + B + C) - A - B = C. So plug in the numbers 1, 2, 3 into A, B, C in all permutations, and you find that if A and B are two different rod numbers, then 6 - A - B always returns the third rod number.